# Narrow down the scope of generic super-interface in implementing classes

Tags: java, generics

Providing I have an interface like:

```
public interface Replicateable<T> {
    void replicate(T entity);
}
```

another one extending it

```
// here Identifiable is just another interface
public interface Entity extends Identifiable, Replicateable<Entity> {
    //some declarations here
}
```

and in the end of this chain I'd like to have something like

```
public class ConcreteEntity implements Entity {
    @Override
    public void replicate(ConcreteEntity entity) {
        // here goes some logic turning current entity
        // to a replica of a passed one
    }
}
```

Any ways to achieve that besides making the `Entity` interface generic? I'd rather avoid that.
So for I tried to
1. Leave as it is, which doesn't work since `replicate()` implementation requires exactly an `Entity` parameter, and not a concrete one
2. Add `Replicateable` right to entity class

```
public class ConcreteEntity implements Entity, Replicateable<ConcreteEntity> { ... }
```

which gave me `'Replicateable' cannot be inherited with different type arguments: 'Entity' and 'ConcreteEntity'` (and it seems understandable why it didn't work).
3. Override `replicate()` in the `Entity` interface (with no results either, not even sure if it's meaningful at all).
4. Make a `replicate()` generic instead of `Replicateable` itself (not sure how to make it right)

Would appreciate any suggestions how to make it right.

Comment: When you say that `Entity` implements `Replicateable<Entity>` it means that the `replicate` method accepts any `Entity` object. Think of `Comparable<Number>` - if your object is `Integer` it still makes sense to it to be comparable to `Double` and vice versa. So it makes sense to put the `Comparable` on the `Number` level. But if your `replicate` method can only be applied to an object of the exact same type, then it must be at that object's level. You can't put it on `Entity`.

Comment: think making Entity generic is best practice but why you'd rather avoid that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me... Why don't you want to make `Entity` generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers, they were insightful and helped me to come up with a suitable solution.
I ended up redefining replicateable interface to

```
public interface Replicateable<T> {
    //note the boolean return type here
    boolean replicate(T entity);
}
```

leaving it as it was in the entity interface, without making it generic

```
public interface Entity extends Identifiable, Replicateable<Entity> {
    //some declarations here
}
```

which allows to not to rewrite tons of code to get rid of raw-types and doesn't break entity's generic method implementations (why it's being broken upon making `Entity` itself is another question out of the scope of this one.)
An the method implementation looks like

```
@Override
public boolean replicate(Entity entity) {
    if (entity.getClass() == ConcreteEntity.class) {
        // replicating logic
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method doesn't create a new object by turns an existing one to a replica of one that was passed to the method, that was the point (I should've mentioned it, my apologies for that). Otherwise I'd use Cloneable, as per some of your suggestions.
So, to sum up and generalize - it's either make `Entity` generic or to use Cloneable (both not my cases) or to invent a workaround, which I did. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`Entity` would have to be generic for the compiler to know which type can be passed to `replicate`:

```
Entity<ConcreteEntity> e = ...;
e.replicate(...); // <-- aha. Can only pass a ConcreteEntity (or a subtype of)
```

---

It might make more sense to use polymorphism:

```
interface Replicateable<T> {
    T replicate();
}

interface Entity extends Identifiable, Replicateable<Entity> {
    // Entity replicate();
}
```

Which could be implemented using copy constructors:

```
class ConcreteEntity implements Entity {
    public ConcreteEntity(ConcreteEntity other) {...}

    @Override
    public ConcreteEntity replicate() { // <-- uses return type overriding
        return new ConcreteEntity(this);
    }
}
```

```
Entity e1 = new ConcreteEntity();
Entity copy1 = e1.replicate();

ConcreteEntity e2 = new ConcreteEntity();
ConcreteEntity copy2 = e2.replicate();
```

Comment: Looks like your `replicate()` creates a new object, whereas the OP's replicate changes the current object in some way to conform to the other object. These are not the same thing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I know, but it might work just as well for what OP wants to do. It's worth suggesting, since they'd rather not have ```Entity``` be generic.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do requires making Entity generic due to the way Generics work in Java. It is a strange pattern but it comes up from time to time.

```
public interface Entity<T extends Entity> extends Identifiable, Replicateable<T> {
    //some declarations here
}

public class ConcreteEntity implements Entity<ConcreteEntity> {
    @Override
    public void replicate(ConcreteEntity entity) {
        // here goes some logic turning current entity
        // to a replica of a passed one
    }
}
```

However there may be a different way of designing your interfaces so that this is not required. What are you trying to do with `replicate`?

Your comments make it sound like you would do the following.

```
SomeEntity a = new SomeEntity();
// set values on a
SomeEntity b = new SomeEntity();
b.replicate(a);
```

**IF** that is what you are trying to do there several other ways to achieve that end result

```
SomeEntity a = new SomeEntity();
// set values on a
SomeEntity b = new SomeEntity(a); // copy constructor
SomeEntity c = a.clone(); // Clone operation
```

See the [PrototypePattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) for a more in depth overview of creating objects based upon the values of other objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without making `Entity` also generic. You should use [F-bounded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

> F-bounded quantification or recursively bounded quantification, introduced in 1989, allows for more precise typing of functions that are applied on recursive types. A recursive type is one that includes a function that uses it as a type for some argument or its return value.

In Java, F-bounded types can be expressed with a generic interface, which in your case would be as follows:

```
public interface Replicateable<T extends Replicateable<T>> {

    void replicate(T entity);
}

public interface Entity<T extends Entity<T>> extends Replicateable<T> {

    //some declarations here
}

public class ConcreteEntity implements Entity<ConcreteEntity> {

    @Override
    public void replicate(ConcreteEntity entity) {

        // here goes some logic turning current entity
        // to a replica of a passed one
    }
}
```